# Installing Raspbian on mdadm raid

Tags: software-installation, pi-4, raid

I'm looking to make a serious Raspberry Pi installation, and a micro sd card is not enough performance or redundancy for me. So I'm trying to figure out how to install Raspbian on a mdadm raid5 array of USB3.0 drives (I'm using the newest Raspberry Pi 4 Model B 4GB).

I know how to set up the mdadm array, but I'm a bit confused about actually installing Raspbian on the new raid device. In theory, I should just be able to have the 256mb boot partition on the SD card, and that boots from the mdadm array with the actual Raspbian OS on it, right? How would I configure grub to do that? And what files do I move to the raid device for this to work properly?

Comment: This might be of help [Raspberrry Pi 3 as a RAID](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/47133/raspberrry-pi-3-as-a-raid)